# How to get Dynamic Cell Value from another Sheet to an Excel Sheet Cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Hope You all doing good .I New to `Excel`. What I'm Looking for is to get a Cell Value from another sheet on the same work book. But the address of the cell cannot predict initially, It depends upon the value entering on the cell of first sheet. I explain my problem with an example I have two sheets `sheet1` and `sheet2` when user enter a value on one cell `sheet1` (assume that is 12) then  I need to get the value of `A12` from `sheet2` to any cell of `sheet1`?.Is there a possible solution without VBA?. Please Help me?

Note :- this value `12` is an example it can `100` ,`5` , `200` or `X` so what I would like to have is the value of cells `A100`, `A5` , `A200` and `AX` from `sheet2`(ie, `=Sheet2!A100`,`=Sheet2!A5`, `=Sheet2!A200` or `=Sheet2!AX`)

[image]

On the above image when user enter a value `1` on `cell C2` of `sheet1` ,I need to get `Sheet2!1` on `cell D2` of `sheet1`
what I have tried is that

> =INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!(B+C3))
> the '+'operator I'm used for concatenation purpose and not for addition
> AND
> =+Sheet2!("B" &C3)

but which is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got the answer it is the `INDIRECT` function, in the above case if user enter the value on cell B2 of sheet1 then the formula is `=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A"&B2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reference to the cell in another sheet.

In a blank cell, type a `=` sign, then click on the sheet and then on the cell. Confirm with the Enter key.

That will create the reference like `=Sheet1!$A$`

Whenever the value in cell A1 on Sheet1 changes, the cell with the formula reference will also change.

Edit: for the scenario you describe, i.e. you provide the row number and the formula gets the data from column A in another sheet, you can use a formula along the following (assuming you enter the number into cell B5 on Sheet2)

```
=Index(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!B5)
```

You enter this formula on Sheet2. In words: Get the value from column A in Sheet1, from the row number that is the same number as cell B5 on Sheet2.

**Edit 2** after screenshot added to question

You may want to learn how to use cell references properly. Your formula has several issues: brackets between sheet and cell reference, cell reference without a row number. It looks like you want to use the result of adding cells B3 and C3 and use that number in the Index function.

When you construct such a formula, you don't need to write `Sheet2!B3` manually. You can just click on the cell you want to use and then Excel will write the formula for you.  Your final formula should look like this:

```
=Index(Sheet1!A:A,B3+C3)
```

You can "write" the formula this way:

- type into cell D3 `=index(` and do NOT hit Enter
- click over to Sheet1 and select column A. The formula then looks like this
  `=index(Sheet1!A:A`
- type a comma
- click on Sheet2 and click cell B3
- type a + sign
- click cell C3
- type a closing bracket for the formula and hit Enter

When you reference cells on the same sheet, you don't have to enter the sheet name. I only did that in my example to illustrate where the cell is located.

Comment: Sorry I think You don't understand my Question well , when we enter a value (for example 5) on one cell , I need to get value of A5 from another sheet

Comment: You just posted answer for a static case .any way thanks for the attempt

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't read the question correctly. I added an answer for your scenario.

Comment: @Sorry I Explained Problem briefly ,I can't predict the cell from sheet2 on first ,It depends on value that user entered on sheet1(it can be any value 1,2,3...) what I needed is '`=Sheet2!A1,=Sheet2!A2,=Sheet2!A3 ,any way thanks for the attempt

Comment: That is exactly what the Index formula I posted does. I just swapped sheet numbers 1 and 2. But you can surely adjust that??

Comment: Sorry I'm just entering value 5 in to the cell on excel sheet1 (not B5)

Comment: I added to my answer. 
If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the tour. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.